# MySQL UNION ALL is too slow

Tags: mysql, performance, union, union-all

I have a query in MySQL from 4 tables. When I run these queries individually they run quick within 1 second.

But when I combine them using `UNION ALL`, machine comes under heavy load and take at least 10 seconds for the same query in `UNION ALL`. And I have digged whole the internet including YouTube, but unfortunately I did not find any solution yet.

Please advise.
Thanks.

`code`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, sessionId FROM promotion
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, sessionId FROM transport_details
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, sessionId FROM fee_details
) a;
```

Comment: I can only see 3 tablese

Comment: I put just 3 tables here for example. Actually it has more than 3 tables.

Comment: But same query is run faster as in MS SQL Server.

Comment: You could have indexes on your ms sql

Comment: let me know the structure of tables

Comment: Dear METAL, All indexes on individual tables are already set. As if I select from individual table rather than union all then there is no issue. Its in miliseconds. But creating issue while union all.

Comment: "just 3 tables here for example" -- Did you leave out `WHERE` clauses, `GROUP BY`, etc??  How big are the tables?  How slow is "too slow"?  Do you need all the rows from all the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all the developers here who participated in my question.

Although I did not find any satisfactory resolution of MySQL `UNION ALL` slow query. But I have managed it up to 80% by optimizing MySQL individual queries.

Also there is a provision to increase the memory and CPU limits.

Comment: _As a side note:_ it would be useful to include the specific changes that led to the performance gains. Otherwise it is not clear.

Comment: @informatik01 thanks for update. I will try to mention the steps. thanks

Answer (score -1):

By creating a temporary table and adding an index to it, will solve your problem

```
id int(11),
sessionId varchar(255),
key id(id)
);

insert into tbl1 (id,sessionId)
select id, sessionId from promotion;

create temporary table tbl2(
id int(11),
sessionId varchar(255),
key id(id)
);
insert into tbl2 (id,sessionId)
select id, sessionId from transport_details;


create temporary table tbl3(
id int(11),
sessionId varchar(255),
key id(id)
);
insert into tbl3 (id,sessionId)
select id, sessionId from fee_details;

select * from tbl1 union all 
select * from tbl2 union all
select * from tbl3
```

Comment: Dear Vaibhav,  I need simple query rather than log codes. Thanks for your attempt.

Comment: did you check, how much time this query takes?

Comment: union all slowdowns the query. because when mysql execute your union query it creates a table in memory and then it combines the result. at this time your indexes are vanished.that's why your query gets slow.

Comment: you are right, individual query is faster because it will give you only result when you are using union all it has few additional work has to perform internally.

Comment: No index is useful.  Manually creating multiple temp tables is _worse_ than letting MySQL create a single temp table and append to it, which is what `UNION ALL` does.  (In version 8 it even avoids the temp table.)

Comment: I am working with more than 10,00,000 records daily. This approach gives me records in milliseconds. where just union all take more than minutes. it works in my case.Like a Lighting speed.